# Why is assert of range( 0, 0 ) return true for any one-element array regardless of its value?

Tags: php, casting, range, assert

These are as expected (per https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
assert( range( 0, 0 ) == [0] );
assert( range( 0, 0 ) == ['0'] );
assert( range( 0, 0 ) !== ['not zero'] );
assert( range( 0, 1 ) != ['not zero', 'not zero'] );
```

But why is `range( 0, 0 )` apparently considered `==` equal to any one-element array regardless of its value?

```
assert( range( 0, 0 ) == ['not zero'] ); // return TRUE??
```

Comment: Everything explained in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better explanation is the `==` operator **convert** the array element to **int** as the left side of the operator was array with int.

Because both `intval('not zero')` and `(int) 'not zero'` will return 0 the compare will return true as it is 0 (as one can see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)).

When using `===` PHP is not doing type casting so the string stays string so the compare fails (from [PHP operators](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)):

> `===`: TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same **types**.